# R: How to fit a large dataset with a combination of distributions?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

To fit a dataset of real-valued numbers (`x`) with one distribution, we can use MASS as follows either the [gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) or [Student's t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) distribution:

```
fitdistr(x, "gamma")
```

or

```
fitdistr(x2, "t")
```

What if I believe my dataset should fit by the sum of gamma and t distributions?

```
P(X) = Gamma(x) + t(x)
```

Can I fit the parameters of mixtures of probability distributions using Maximum Likelihood fitting in R?

Comment: I assume you mean (as the other posters have also assumed) that your distribution is a *mixture* of Gamma and t (i.e. that each individual point is drawn either from the Gamma or t distributions).  The other alternative, which is a bit trickier, is that (as I would think if I read your question literally) that the individual values are sums of Gamma and t variables, i.e. that the distribution is a convolution of Gamma and t.  Please clarify.  If it is the latter I can suggest a solution using the `distr` package ...

Comment: More than two years later and not the original poster, but I'd be very interested in your proposed solution for the convolution using the `distr` package.

Answer (score 3):

There are analytic [maximum-likelihood estimators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) for some parameters, such as the mean of a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) or the rate of an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). For other parameters, there is no analytic estimator, but you can use [numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) to find reasonable parameter estimates.

The [fitdistr()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html) function in R uses numerical optimization of the log-likelihood function by calling the [optim()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/optim.html) function. If you think that your data is a mixture of Gamma and t distribution, then simply make a likelihood function that describes such a mixture. Then, pass those parameter values to optim() for optimization. Here is an example using this approach to fitting a distribution:

```
library( MASS )

vals = rnorm( n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1 ) 
print( summary(x_vals) )

ll_func = function(params) {
   log_probs = log( dnorm( x = vals, mean = params[1], sd = params[2] ))
   tot = sum(log_probs)
   return(-1 * tot)
}       

params = c( 0.5, 10 )

print( ll_func(params) )
res = optim( params, ll_func )
print( res$par )
```

Running this program in R produces this output:

```
[1] "mean: 0.0223766157516646"
[1] "sd:   0.991566611447471"
```

That's fairly close to the initial values of mean = 0 and sd = 1.

Don't forget that with a mixture of two distributions, you have one extra parameter that specifies the relative weights between the distributions. Also, be careful about fitting lots of parameters at once. With lots of free parameters you need to worry about [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Answer (score 2):

Try mixdist.  Here's an example of a mixture of three distributions:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/which-r-package-to-use-to-calculate-component-parameters-for-a-mixture-model